# Django: can't access values of dictionary in template

Tags: python, django

I have a view with the following code:

```
@login_required
def grouping(request, project_id):
    groups = {}
    order = {}

    # Bind parameters to variables and return a 404 if one is considered incorrect
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if request.GET.get('filter%i' % i, None) is not None:
            try:
                order[i] = int(request.GET.get('filter%i' % i, None))
            except ValueError:
                return projects_overview(request, 'Incorrect filter parameters passed', 404)

    if order == {}:
        return projects_overview(request, 'Incorrect filter parameters passed', 404)

    original_properties = []

    # Put all of the originally passed properties in a list
    for key in order:
        property = Property.objects.get(pk=order[key])
        original_properties.append(property)

    # Get the corresponding category and project
    category = original_properties[0].category
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)

    objects = Object.objects.filter(project=project, type__category=category)

    # Group the objects with the same property values together
    for object in objects:
        properties = object.property_set.all().order_by('name')
        values = []
        for property in properties:
            if property.original_property in original_properties:
                values.append(property.value)
        values_json = json.dumps(values)
        if groups.get(values_json) is None:
            groups[values_json] = []
        groups[values_json].append(object)
    print(groups)

    return render(request, 'dashboard/groups.html', {'groups': groups, 'project': project,
                                                     'function_create_form': ObjectForm(project_id=project_id)})
```

The problem is the variable `groups`, which returns something like this:

```
{'["a", "b", "c"]': [<Object: Object 3>, <Object: Object 4>], '["q", "w", "e"]': [<Object: Object 5>]}
```

Now I am trying to iterate over this in my template:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me the keys, which makes sense:

```
["a", "b", "c"] ["q", "w", "e"]
```

But actually I only care about the list that is attached to the key. So I do:

```
{% for key, group in groups %}
    {{ key }}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which gives me the following error:
`Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 15.`

So I tried this, but that just gives me the key, character by character like I already expected:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {% for object in group %}
        {{ object }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I've never had this problem before, does it have to do with the way I've structured the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To loop over the key-value pairs in a dictionary, use the `items` method.

```
{% for key, group in groups.items %}
    {{ key }}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you just want the values, use `values`:

```
{% for group in groups.values %}
    {{ group }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 2.x:

```
for key, value in groups.iteritems():
    {{ key }}
    {{ value }}
```

For Python 3.x:

```
for key, value in groups.items():
    {{ key }}
    {{ value }}
```